# Defining Exponential Preprocessor Macro

Tags: c++, macros

I'm planning on competing in a programming competition in a few months, and I want to define some macros to minimize the typing i need to do.  Raising a number to a power is common enough to benefit from this I've been told.  I only need it to work with integer arguments (though the arguments themselves may be expressions). I've tried a few different variations but I can't get the correct syntax.

```cpp
/* c is where the result is stored */
#define EXP(a,b,c) c=a; for (int ii=0; ii<(b)-1; c*=(a), ii++);
```

This works but i can't use EXP(a,b,c) in an expression like `function( EXP(a,b,c) );` I'd have to do

```cpp
int result; 
EXP(a,b,result); 
function(result);
```

This, I think would work inside expressions but it fails to compile

```cpp
#define EXP(a,b) int c=a; for (int ii=0; ii<(b)-1; (c)*=(a), i++); c
```

with: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’` when used in:

```cpp
int result = EXP(2,10);
```

this is my representative function:

```cpp
int EXP(int base, int power) {
  int result = base;
  for (int ii=0; ii<power-1; ii++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This being C++, is there a specific reason for you to aim for a macro instead of an inline function?

Comment: This being C++, have you considered template metaprogramming?

Comment: normally i'd just inline the function. At the competition there is only one computer per team of 3,  each member taking turns. I would need to write out my program on paper first, then type into the computer as fast as I can.  Practically speaking though, I probably won't save a lot of time with the macro I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a *macro function* is the wrong tool for the job. Nevertheless, you say *you think it would work inside expressions*, consider how would that look for the actual compiler once the preprocessor did his work:

```
int result = int c=2; for (int ii=0; ii<(10)-1; (c)*=(2), i++); c
```

No matter how hard you try, you can't do variable definitions nor `for` loops within an expression.

Comment: I had seen [these](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/icpc/icpc_programming_tips.html) and thought it might be possible. It's the 3rd heading from the top: "(C/C++) The dreaded #define" (sorry there were no anchor tags)

Comment: @xst: No, those can't be used within expressions either. Btw, why would you want a _dreader_ macro instead of a regular function?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursive template template approach:

```
template<int base, unsigned int exp>
struct Pow {
    enum { value = base * power<base, exp-1>::value };
};
// stopping condition
template<int base>
struct Pow<base,0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

and use it like this:

```
int i = Pow<10,2>::value;
```